# Large data with Kendo ComboBox

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, datasource

I would like to list a large data into a Kendo ComboBox (between 10k and 60k).

Data set is saved into an Javascript array to improve loading time.

My problem is that the browser freeze.
It works with 6k items but it's slow.
It works when there is little data.

Here is the code :

```
var $input = $('<input class="criterion-value-input"/>');  
var kendoParams = {
    dataSource: dataSource,
    dataTextField: 't',
    dataValueField: 'v',
    autoBind: true,
    filter: 'contains',
    placeholder: 'Valeur...',
    suggest: false,
    select: function(e) {
        that._dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    }
};
$input.kendoComboBox(kendoParams);
```

The datasource looks like this :

```
0: Object
    t: "[7773077397] SAACY SUR MARNE (SAACY SUR MARNE)"
    v: "7773077397"
1: Object
    t: "[6742067421] SAALES (SAALES)"
    v: "6742067421"
2: Object
    t: "[7673076549] SAANE ST JUST (SAANE ST JUST)"
    v: "7673076549"
3: Object
    t: "[6739067422] SAASENHEIM (SAASENHEIM)"
    v: "6739067422"
[...]
60000: Object
    t: "[1234512345] ZZZZZ (ZZZZZ)"
    v: "1234512345"
```

v is the value, t is the text.

There is a max count items ?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such limit is just a question of memory and CPU. Each element in your ComboBox gets translated to an HTML piece of code that needs to be rendered (despite not displayed). So I would say that 60000 is a way to large number of HTML (DOM) nodes to manage.

Did you consider using [server side filtering](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering)?

Comment: how would i manage loading lets say million of records in the combobox. in my scenario when i load it all, it generates error or it is too slow

Comment: Does it make sense loading millions? Loading from the server will be slow as well as rendering. Why not using server side filtering?

Comment: how would i implement that?? for example i want to filter it for minimum of three letters?? but when i click on the arrow icon, it will fire the read event. can you please site an example. because in our project we use combobox to look up for items which may become millions and we got javascript timeout

Comment: For the minimum of three letters you should set `minLength` to `3` when creating the ComboBox.

Comment: yup. i've tried that. but when i click the arrow with empty input, it loads all the data and boom javascript error.. what i wan is to make sure there is value in the input is not empty

Comment: And how many records do you think that you will have those 3 letters? many? you can limit the pagesize so you will only receive a maximum of the pagesize and then use virtual scroll in the datasource. A lot of work in the server but when dealing with millions...

Comment: is it possible to add virtual scroll on the datasource of a kendo combobox??

Comment: as said in this article it doesn't http://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-with-large-remote-datasource i am a bit confused

Comment: that's what we are trying to solve the virtual scrolling but its not yet a feature of the combobox it can only hold 5000+ records based on my test

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your dataSource:

```
PageSize:10
```

Also 20 could be a good PageSize value. However, make sure to use a PageSize less than 100 because Kendo can render at most 100 item Speedily.

In comboBox HTML write

```
filer:contains ...
```

this will solve your problem